# How to replace a Template using Deface

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, deface

I'm new to rails and I've set up a standard spree e commerce solution. I now want to customize the default templates and styles. According to the spree documentation [1], the best way to do so is using Deface. Unfortunately, I can't figure out the location of the existing views/layouts.

For example, while the document suggests:

> For example, to override the main layout, create the file `YOUR_SITE_OR_EXTENSION/app/views/spree/layouts/spree_application.html.erb`

my `app/views` folder doesn't contain a folder called `spree`

Can anybody tell me, how to change the view templates?

Thank you.

[1] https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/view.html

Comment: have you tried just creating that directory?

Comment: I just did, but no effect even after restarting the ruby application :(

Comment: so you've added an application layout in the location above, with the above name - and with different content (so you know it's working or not) and it isn't using the other layout?

Comment: I now also tried to insert the layout `spree_application.html.erb` without adding content. My main page is blank now. So it seems to work. But my actual question is, where can I find the original layout pages in order to change them? Also, if I just edit the layout file, it will completely change. But I think it'd be a better idea to use Deface, so the original layout pages don't need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually create that directory and every directory along the way until you reach the file you wish to override. If you run these commands from your root directory you should be good to go.

```
mkdir app/views/spree
mkdir app/views/spree/layouts
touch app/views/spree/layouts/application.html.erb
```

Then copy the content from here: https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/frontend/app/views/spree/layouts/spree_application.html.erb into the file you've just created.

If you restart your web server you should be able to make changes to the local application.html.erb file and see them locally.

Any time you want to override a template completely, you can find the template you need to override on Github: https://github.com/spree/spree and recreate the necessary files/directories. Spree will look for templates in on localhost before the gem, so as long as you override the right template in the right directory, you can customize any view you like.

Comment: If I run these commands, it will create me the folders and the application.html.erb file, which is empty and it won't change even after restarting the application. What I'm trying to achieve is getting all views so I can change those I'd like to. But so far the structure of the default view files is unknown to me..

Comment: See the edit. You can override any template you like as long as it is in the same path locally as it is in the Spree gem.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can try running the rails generate spree:frontend:copy_views command to pull all the views you need from gems, and anything that is missing can be added manually, in strict accordance with the gems folder hierarchy. For example, in gems is parsl in the following spree_backend/views/spree/admin/users/_lifetime_stats.html.erb. To enter the desired code, I have to make a folder on the following path - the name of the project/app/views/spree/admin/users/_lifetime_stats.html.the erb and all the changes I will make here will fall into the main view code. This is an alternative to Deface::override